# nodejs POST request is not posting to db and returns 302 response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been working on a basic CRUD app in node.js, express, mongodb and working with tutorials I've tried to set it up on my own. I'm not sure why I'm getting a 302 response on my POST request.

```
router.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    mongoose.model('User').find({}, function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } else {
            res.format({
                html: function() {
                    res.render('users/index', {
                        title: 'All Users',
                        "users": users
                    });
                },
                json: function() {
                    res.json(users);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
.post(function(req,res) {
    // get values from post request
    var name = req.body.name;
    var iscool = req.body.iscool;
    // call the create function from mongoose
    mongoose.model('User').create({
        name: name,
        iscool: iscool
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("There was a problem connecting to db");
        } else {
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            console.log('Creating POST for ' + user.name);
            res.format({
                html: function() {
                    // if successful, set header address bar to "users"
                    res.location("users");
                    res.redirect("/users");
                },
                json: function() {
                    res.json(user);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Where I console.log(res.statusCode) it returns a 200 OK response but in my Chrome Dev Tools I'm getting a 302 response in my network requests. I'm just really confused as to where I should look for my error. My form's action is set to /users and the router uses (/users) for the users controller and routes.

Here is the form as well:

```
<form name="adduser" action="/users" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="iscool">Are you cool?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="iscool">
<div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Any help is appeciated and apologies for the spacing!

Comment: Hi, you probably need to use express _method-override_ and _body-parser_, also setting the _enctype_ to the form:

`<form method="POST" action="/users" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`

Comment: @ricardo-fornes so is the _method-override_ needed? I took it out on purpose from the tutorial because I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: Yes, _method-override_ middleware is not a must, is only required if you want to use methods like DELETE & PUT (not supported in some browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you already have this on your app's middleware, but you can try using the *body-parser* middleware to parse *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*:

**In your terminal:**

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

**Your form:**

```
...
<form method="POST" action="/users" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
...
```

**Then in your app:**

```
...
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
...
```

- [Posting form data with Nodejs and body-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435539/posting-form-data-with-nodejs-and-body-parser)
- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 res.redirect("/users");
```

When you do this, it returns a 302 status code. Use `res.render` like you did in the get request above to get a 200 back.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, I guess before anything, nothing is getting POSTed to my database for some reason. Also the res.render is showing /users is showing things without data while /users/ shows with data from the ejs file. You see anything wrong with my code that stands out?

Comment: @DannyKim It's because you have no POST handler for your `/users` request.
You should remove your `.post(function...)` and add it on your `/users` path. Something like this:

`router.route('/users').post(function(req,res) {...})` 

As you see, your current `.post` handler is on the root route `/`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect and not to render just remove `res.format()` with a normal `res.redirect()`. Mixing between them in  your way will never work.

**Replace:**

```
res.format({
  html: function() {
      // if successful, set header address bar to "users"
      res.location("users");
      res.redirect("/users");
  },
  json: function() {
      res.json(user);
  }
});
```

**With:**

```
res.redirect("/users");
```